# SQL code to find the total sum of sales amount by each person by day

Tags: sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UGmM.png)

Hi, I have a data table shown in the image above. I want a result whereby the code finds each person's total (sum) sales amount by day.
e.g., for Salesperson Frank, it returns his sales for Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc.

Thanks

Comment: can you share your coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server

Comment: You could use an aggregate but in the sample data you posted there are no rows for the same person on the same day.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SalesPerson, Week, Day, SUM(SalesAmount)
FROM myTABLE
GROUP BY SalesPerson, Week, Day
ORDER BY SalesPerson, Week
```

Use a day number field if you want to order by week day.

If you don't want to group by week, suppress `Week` field from previous query.